# Swift Custom UITableViewCell Programmatically works and shows in cell but Storyboard IBOutlet is nil and does not show in cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

In my custom cell swift file  CustomTableView.swift, I can create programmatically the labels for my TableView but when I use IBOutlet in Storyboard the label becomes always nil

I am very sure that my cell is not nil

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var lblPostDate: UILabel!

    var message: UILabel = UILabel()



    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.message.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);
        self.message.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        self.message.text = "bla bla bla bla bla"
        self.addSubview(self.message)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func setCell(postDate: String)
    {
        self.lblPostDate?.text = postDate

    }

}
```

In the above code, the message can be seen in the cells but lblPostDate which is the IBOutlet can not be seen

I am sure about the delegate and datasource and custom cell identifier what so ever but it seems that the IBOutlets don't get initialized correctly. I can see that lblPostDate becomes nil when I debug

Is this a bug of XCode 6?

Here is how I call from my Controller

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var items = ["one","two","three","four"]

    let kCellIdentifier: String = "CustomCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var mTableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.mTableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier)
        //self.mTableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:CustomTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)  as? CustomTableViewCell

        if (cell == nil) {

            self.mTableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
        }

        if var label = cell.lblPostDate{
            label.text = items[indexPath.row]
        }
        else{
            cell.setCell(items[indexPath.row])
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func  tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you connected lblPostDate from Storyboard to file? I am sure you haven't

Comment: Yes I did connect from Storyboard to the cell class file..  I guess somehow it doesn't recognize it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is insane, I deleted the register class code and it worked, I can't believe it

```
//self.mTableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier)
```

After commenting out the registerClass in my Controller, it doesn't call anymore the init function but creates the lblPostDate correctly indeed

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.message.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);
        self.message.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        self.message.text = "bla bla bla bla bla"
        self.addSubview(self.message)
    }
```

So I don't need anymore to create hard-code input objects.

It is interesting that all the tutorials, everywhere they suggest to register the class. Anyway,it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the lblPostDate with one label in your cell xib file.

Comment: I am using Storyboard and linked it to my cell class file.. I don't have to use xib file if I use Storyboard right?